# Facing issue while creating a Bucket in IBM COS S3

Tags: object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

There are four APIs available to create a Bucket in IBM COS S3. but I'm only able to access one API, that is of creating a "STANDARD" bucket. other three APIs that is for creating a "vault bucket","cold vault bucket" and "flex bucket" I'm not able to access. for all these I'm getting "the provided provisioning code is invalid error".

while creating a "STANDARD" bucket we don't need to provide body in request I only provide "region" header .I'm able to access this API.

for all other three API we have to provide location constraint details as per API docs:

```
<CreateBucketConfiguration>
  <LocationConstraint>us-vault</LocationConstraint>
</CreateBucketConfiguration>
```

my request header is like this:

```
{
host:"lb1.ait.cleversafelabs.com",
path:"/democoldbucket",
service:"s3",
region:"us-cold",
body:data,
method:"PUT",
headers:{
'Content-Type':'text/plain'
}

}
```

and I'm using "aws4" module for signing requests.

I'm not sure whether I'm making some mistake or these Functionalities are not accessible from REST API.

could you please confirm on this.

Answer (score 0):

Those values are intended for use with IBM Cloud endpoints, such as "s3.us-south.objectstorage.softlayer.net". If you have your own COS system (aka dsNet) set up, then those values correspond to any container vaults or provisioning codes.

Comment: sorry i didn't get it...

can you please let me know if i can access these api for clevOS

Comment: This documentation is for the public cloud implementation of IBM COS, which is essentially an extremely large dsNet running in Container Mode.  Because you are making requests against your own system, the example you provided is looking for a Container Vault with the provisioning code `us-vault`.  If you haven't set up that Container Vault then these will fail.

So to answer your question - no, these API calls are not supported in an out-of-the-box COS installation, only in the hosted public cloud service available through Softlayer/Bluemix Infrastructure.